# windowNoTitle don't work

Tags: android, titlebar

I already set the **windowNoTitle** as true,and The activty  extends **AppCompatActivity**.But when I run the app,the title bar still exists.How to hide it?

There are a part of codes in **Manifest**:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ScrollingActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and the style of **ScrollingActivity**:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

If you need more details,[here is my project on github](https://github.com/fly904021125/MyApplication),thanks for any helps.

Comment: Please don't just link to your project off-site. You need to include a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: @MikeM.     Thank you for reminding me

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.It's because of the variable style resources.I just modified the wrong style file.